# PHP login return values

Tags: php

```
  function procLogin($username,$password){

     $query = "SELECT *
                      FROM members
                      WHERE login = '".mysql_escape_string($username)."'
                      AND passwd = '".mysql_escape_string($password)."'";
        $result = mysql_query($query);


        //$values = array();
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
        {
                return 'gg';
                return(array($row['member_id']));
        }



}
```

Not able to get the userlevel field.... nor anything....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

return(array($row['member_id']));

Looks wrong - it should be:

return($row['member_id']);

You shouldn't need to define the array in the return like that.

You also use mysql_fetch_array () which returns as a numerical index - the function you probably want is mysql_fetch_assoc which is much nicer to work with as it returns the values with the keys as the column name rather than a numerical index.

Here's it again with a few tidy ups:

```
function procLogin($username,$password){
    $query = "SELECT *
         FROM members
         WHERE login = '".mysql_escape_string($username)."'
         AND passwd = '".mysql_escape_string($password)."'";
    $result = mysql_query($query);

    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result); 

    if ($row['member_id'] > 0)
    {
        return ($row['member_id']);
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I am getting the return value as false, though the userlevel has a value for the current user which is checked.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure exactly what your question is, but one problem is that you're `return`ing from within this while loop:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
{
  return 'gg';
  return(array($row['member_id']));
}
```

In fact, you're returning **twice** from within the loop... so the `procLogin()` function will always return a value of "gg", unless something goes wrong with your SQL query.

In general, you should avoid `return` statements within any loop, as it creates confusion and can lead to unexpected results.

Comment: There is also no point in have this in a while loop. A simple if on the value of $row would be enough.

Comment: How to get the userlevel without a while loop

Answer (score 1):

I'm thinking, based on your comments about the userlevel, that you want to return the entire array rather than just the member_id ?   Here's a slight edit to Meep3D's answer above:

```
function procLogin($username,$password){
    $query = "SELECT *
         FROM members
         WHERE login = '".mysql_escape_string($username)."'
         AND passwd = '".mysql_escape_string($password)."'";
    $result = mysql_query($query);

    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result); 

    if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)
    {
        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result); 
        return $row;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

This should return an array of all your table columns, if you are looking for the userlevel, presumably you should be able to access it something like:

```
$loginInfo = procLogin("theband","password1");
//if ($loginInfo) or something similar here
$level = $loginInfo['userlevel'];
```

Comment: I dont need the entire info, just the userlevel of the current user being checked. Also your code also returns false...

Comment: So just return the userlevel:
return $row['userlevel'];

Are you certain you are getting the expected result from the database?

Answer (score 0):

So are you getting anything returned? That is to say, is it actually going into the while loop?

I'd use a mysql_error() function call straight after the mysql_query call to see if anything went wrong there.

Maybe there was no connection made, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Are you still having issues?  If so try something like:

```
echo $query;
```

after you define the query, then copy+paste that into phpmyadmin to check if there are any valid returns from the database.

After that try placing:

```
if (mysql_error())
{
    trigger_error ("MySQL Error: ". mysql_error(), E_USER_ERROR);
}
```

Just after you call mysql_query.  This should trigger an error if there is one giving you details of what went wrong.

Comment: It got resolved, the problem was i was not using MD5 to encrypt.